# Django: Unable to open a detail view by URL, which causes reverse argument errors in another view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Python 3.5.1
Django 1.10

Been tearing my hair out for hours on this, but have my Reverse Argument error pinned down to the actual problem.

When I try to open a form to edit a particular record in my model, it only opens a blank (unconnected) form. Using the same logic, I am able to delete a record, so I'm sure this is something stupid-simple. But I'm too many hours into this, so I would appreciate a lifeline.

From models.py

```
class CmsSpaces(models.Model):
sid = models.AutoField(db_column='SID', primary_key=True)
section = models.CharField(db_column='Section', max_length=5)
...Many more columns...

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('cms_spaces:space_edit', args = (self.sid), kwargs=None)
    return reverse('cms_spaces:space_delete', args = (self.sid), kwargs=None)
    return reverse('cms_spaces:space_new', args = None, kwargs = None)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'cms_spaces'
```

From views.py

```
def CmsSpaces_update(request, sid, 
template_name='space_edit.html'):
    space = get_object_or_404(CmsSpaces, sid=sid)
    form = space_form(request.POST or None, instance=space)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('space_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':space_form})

def CmsSpaces_delete(request, sid, 
template_name='space_delete.html'):
    space  = get_object_or_404(CmsSpaces, sid=sid)    
    if request.method=='POST':
        space.delete()
        return redirect('space_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'object':CmsSpaces})
```

From urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from cms_spaces import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^space_list/$', views.CmsSpaces_list, name='space_list'),
  url(r'^space_new/$', views.CmsSpaces_create, name='space_new'),
  url(r'^space_edit/(?P<sid>[\w-]+)/$', views.CmsSpaces_update, name='space_edit'),
  url(r'^space_delete/(?P<sid>[\w-]+)/$', views.CmsSpaces_delete, name='space_delete'),
]
```

From space_edit.html. When I enter the url directly for .../space_delete/12345, it does proceed to delete the record with sid=12345.

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add or Update Space" />
</form>
```

From space_list.html (which throws "Reverse for 'space_edit' with arguments '(10256,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []") as an error. 10256 is in fact an sid for one of the  records in the table. When I remove the links to space_edit and space_delete, it does render the list of records. Yes, there are many more lines of code that handle presentation, but this is the boiled down version, and it is "broken" even at this level.

```
<ul>
    {% for CmsSpaces in space_list %}
    <li>{{CmsSpaces.sid}} {{ CmsSpaces.section }}  {{ CmsSpaces.space}} {{ CmsSpaces.lot }} {{ CmsSpaces.deednum}}
    <a href="{% url 'space_edit' CmsSpaces.sid %}">edit</a>
    <a href="{% url 'space_delete' CmsSpaces.sid %}">delete</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

All I want to do is be able to call and edit a record. If I can do that, I believe the list view will work, and then I'm well on my way to home free. The issue seems to be that even though it is correctly capturing the sid, it is failing to correctly pass it as an argument to the model. Help! Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from masterdata.models import CmsSpaces

class space_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CmsSpaces
        fields = [
        'sid', 
        'section', 
        'space', 
        'lot',
        'deednum', 
        'purchdate', 
        'notes', 
        'perpetualcare',


        ]
```

Comment: I am sorry that I don't have a solution for you, but wanted to point out something: it seems like a bad idea to be able to delete by just typing in a url. Maybe this is what you want, but unless I am mistaken, deleting by url shouldn't be possible if your the request needs to be a `POST` to delete.

Comment: Granted. This was the ripped and stripped version. I wanted to eliminate as much code as possible while still reproducing the error. Process of elimination.

Comment: Got it. Hope you get it sorted!

Comment: Do you have an `app_name` defined in your `urls.py`, or did you pass a namespace to `include()`? The error says `0 pattern(s) tried`, so it can't find a url pattern with just the name `space_edit`.

Comment: Indeed there is (at least I think so, from the code I posted). The issue is that it should be space_edit/<sid> (e.g. space_edit/12345. When I manually enter it in that fashion, it brings me to the edit form, but does not have the data from the selected record. What is most odd is that if I run space_delete/12345, it will in fact delete the record in question.

Comment: Feeling stupid! No... really stupid. In my project urls.py, I had set up the include, but had specified a namespace that I never used again. Here I was, looking for the problem in the app, but the issue was in the project. Thanks @knbk for putting me on the track.

Comment: But now switching gears: the list view works, but "edit" still only gives me a blank form, not one matched to the actual record I mean to edit. I had thought that this was causing the error, but @knbk straightened me out on that. Still part of my original question though...

Comment: Can you show the form class?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the code. Multi-line code in comments in quite hard to read.

Comment: Done. Thanks @knbk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... first off a big thanks to @knbk for getting me on track with the list issue.

Second, my initial diagnosis in the OP was wrong. The issue was in my CmsSpaces_update view. Boiled down, the view had the pieces to tie the form to the record, but no actual code to do so. *slaps head*

So because someone else may someday read this and wonder the same thing...

```
def CmsSpaces_update(request, sid, 
template_name='templates/space_edit.html'):
    space = get_object_or_404(CmsSpaces, sid=sid)
    form = space_form(request.POST or None, instance=space)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('space_list')
    ctx = {}
    ctx['form'] = form
    ctx['space'] = space
    return render(request, template_name, ctx)
```